# CORS working on my pc with no errors, but not working on any other device

Tags: php, cors

This is my code for CORS . I have uploaded my website on https://in.000webhost.com/(it is a free web hosting service. I have this code in my controller.php page. Now when i try to access the website via the url from my pc , it works fine. But if i use any other device to access the website via the url , the part of the page which I display through an AJAX call to controller.php doesn't work and error is shown which says( refer image)[image] The resource is Controller.php ,the same file which has the CORS headers.

```
 if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
      
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");  
    }else{
        header("Access-control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
    }
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
      header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    
    
      if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
            
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
          
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");         
        
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
    
        exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to update the ajax request URL from

**http://localhost/myprojects/test_MaruthiSolar/bootstrap-4.1.3-dist/controller.php**

to something like this

**https://maruthisolar.000webhostapp.com/myprojects/test_MaruthiSolar/bootstrap-4.1.3-dist/controller.php**

Comment: Localhost is equivalent to 127.0.0.1. I would bet the reason it is working on your computer now is because you have a local copy running with apache or ```php -S localhost:80 index.php```. If you stop your local server it will fail on your computer as well. Once you change your url to reflect the post here, you should consider why your disabling COORS. It is a security feature that should only be disabled when you absolutely know the risks. I would recommend you to not do this as it can be avoided.

Comment: I have updated the ajax request url, but it still hasn't solved the problem. When i checked the response in the console , it is returning the response, but not displaying it. It is showing an error : Cannot modify header information. Headers already sent by ........controller.php.

Comment: It is working now, I had to remove white spaces before the <?php opening tag and after the php? closing tag.